# How to revoke a macro in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

After the execution of a macro in Excel, there's no button to revoke it, unless you close the book and choose not to save it.

Is there a neat and easy way to just revoke it?

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is you can't Undo (I assume this is what you mean by revoke) the actions of a macro. The decisions that take place inside the programming language could be troublesome for Excel to reverse, so there is a blanket "Can't Undo" state induced by kicking off the macro.

The long answer is that if you anticipate Undo being required, your code should accommodate that request by storing the previous state of the data before execution. This is a very broad assumption that you are working with data in VBA; direct file creation and manipulation could be trickier depending on what's executed.

John Walkenbach gives a good example of storing data to provide a future Undo facility:

> Computer users are accustomed to the ability to "undo" an operation. Almost every operation you perform in Excel can be undone. If you program in VBA, you may have wondered if it's possible to undo the effects of a subroutine. The answer is yes. The qualified answer is it's not always easy.

[John Walkenbach, Spreadsheetpage.com](http://spreadsheetpage.com/index.php/tip/undoing_a_vba_subroutine/)

I think his opening statement is a little misleading though: for non-coding users the answer is "no, you can't undo a macro".

Comment: I do not quite understand this part:

"this is a very broad assumption that you are working with data in VBA; direct file creation and manipulation could be trickier depending on what's executed."

Comment: If you are working just with data in an Excel workbook (e.g. text, numbers, dates, formulas...) then being able to restore its previous value is relatively easy, as per the link in my answer. However the range of things you can manipulate with VBA is pretty big, and you could be moving files around a network, modifying the contents of a hard drive, converting file formats and more. Trying to provide an Undo state for these operations will get laborious. Feasible though.

Comment: Gary, I am working just with data in Excel workbook, could help on giving an easy solution to go back from the execution of a macro?

Comment: To go back from a macro you need to record / write another macro beforehand and probably have a good working knowledge of VBA.

Comment: ,does that mean I have to write another macro for every new macro I intend to create?There is no a single macro can be created for going back from all macro execution?

Comment: That's correct. There's no magic 'undo' button or macro.

Comment: ok tks! So what you suggest if I need to test in a sheet different macros for many times, and during the process I need to go back,and find it really annoying to exit excel and select' not save' then reopen the same file again? Is there an easy way?

Comment: If you're talking about a single sheet, record yourself duplicating the sheet. This backup can then be restored quickly.

Comment: I am talking about a single sheet, but the fact is I am testing macro on the sheet quite intensively, so does that mean I have to mass copy my sheet? That will result in a lot of docs with the same name in my folder. Any better idea?

Comment: In Excel, drag the worksheet tab to the right or left while holding the CTRL key. Or copy all the data in the sheet, insert a new sheet and paste.

Comment: sorry for being hard to please:)But that's just copy the sheet once at a time, is there any batch copy way?So that i could immediately have many copies of that and try macro with them 1 after another.

Comment: Select multiple sheets with CTRL or Shift keys and then copy etc.

Comment: what i mean is to copy the same sheet into several sheets at just one go, is that possible? Btw, you mean to include all the copies in the same existing open workbook right?

Comment: do you mean select multiple source sheets with ctrl or shift,or destination sheets?

Comment: @frog Maybe you should break the more specific questions into a new question. Your original was answered. There's no system "Undo" for macros.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can undo all actions of a macro.
This is a macro below assigned to a do a DO button.

```
Sub do_while()
    Dim num As Integer
    num = 1
    Do While num <= 12
        Cells(num, 1) = num
        num = num + 1
    Loop
End Sub
The code below is   assigned to an UNDO button.It uses ClearContents.
 Dim num As Integer
    num = 1
    Do While num <= 12
        Cells(num, 1).ClearContents
        num = num + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

Use clear contents.